# Connection closed on first chunked response

Tags: java, http, stream, inputstream, okhttp

I'm using the OkHttp client library to make HTTP requests and I'm having trouble with chunked responses. Specifically, if the response is chunked and I don't use the InputStream to read the response data right away, the connection is closed after receiving the first chunk. The response sends a byte to keep the connection active (as explained here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-idle-timeout.html) if the request takes more than one hour to get processed.

The reason I'm not using the InputStream right away is because it's actually used by the end user of my app to generate a result, but only when my user needs it. What can I do to keep the connection active and receive all chunks of data even if I don't process the first chunk right away?

Thanks!